# How can I make my data efficient and "light" to do 3D Visualizations in Google Earth?

Tags: qgis, 3d, visualisation, google-earth, fly-through

As a test run, I'd like to visualize population on census blocks for a few states (New England for example). I assume that the kml to do this will be huge, when you factor in the census boundaries and population data.

How can I make my data efficient to be able to do such visualizations keeping in mind that I might extend this to having multiple census periods, and doing a time lapse combined with a flythrough?

Also note that usage of Google Earth isn't necessary. I'm open to using QGIS

Comment: don't assume, create a network kml that will pull data on demand when requested - Geoserver can do this. http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/googleearth/overview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this by converting shapefiles into rasters with a large gridcell size, and then converting these rasters back to polygons, and then to KML format. This is an easy way of simplifying the data, but I think it also looks better in a visualization.

(I'm happy to share the code, though it is for ArcGIS 10).

Comment: We're still using 9.3.1

Answer (score 2):

You could generalize the boundaries and remove excess points. Fewer points = less data = more efficient. It would be less accurate, but then I get the feeling the visualization is more important than exact positional accuracy.

Or you could replace the census area polygons with a circle (max size that fits inside the boundary?). Again, if visualization is the key then it needn't be exact map boundaries that you are showing.

I like the idea of a network link, but I wonder how well it would work when doing a flythrough. Could it fetch data fast enough???

Comment: I'd like to get away from the idea of a network link, we're not setup to doing so, and I don't think there is interest to using geoserver at the moment